# Setup a proxy (Not reverse proxy) using Varnish/Squid

Tags: proxy, squid, varnish

I need to setup a proxy server where we can request remote urls and get them served locally.

Basically what I need is

`mysever:8000/varnish/serverfault.com` get me serverfault.com served from my local varnish

or

`myserver:8080/squid/serverfault.com` get me serverfault.com served from my local squid.

(Both should cache the site for 24 hours)

I am evaluating if

1. Varnish or Squid will be a good choice for it.
2. Which one will be a better fit?
3. How do I do it. Links to tutorials would be good.

Answer (score 1):

It would be fairly straightforward to do with squid - using a urlrewriter which checks the mtime on the local copy (if available) and downloads a new copy to the server filesystem is its required.

See http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html for an example of how to do something similar.